# Fix row organization HTML (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

On my website [www.asistaliavalencia.com](http://www.asistaliavalencia.com), on the main page, I have a button bar. I would like to be able to arrange them so that they are all in the same row.
What html code can I add?

```
<div class="boxes-home">
    **<section class="container">
        <div class="row no-margin-negative justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center pt-20-mb">**
                <a href="https://asistaliavalencia.com/cuidadora-ancianos-valencia-por-horas/">
                    <div class="box-home">
                        <img src="https://asistaliavalencia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/icon-home-1.png">
                        <p>Cuidadora de mayores por horas</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                <a href="https://asistaliavalencia.com/cuidadora-de-ancianos-interna-en-valencia/">
                    <div class="box-home">
                        <img src="https://asistaliavalencia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/icon-home-2.png">
                        <p>Cuidadora de mayores interna</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                <a href="https://asistaliavalencia.com/servicio-acompanamiento-en-hospitales-valencia/">
                    <div class="box-home">
                        <img src="https://asistaliavalencia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/icon-home-3.png">
                        <p>Servicio de acompañamiento en hospitales</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                <a href="https://asistaliavalencia.com/servicios-quiropracticos-ancianos-valencia/">
                    <div class="box-home">
                        <img src="https://asistaliavalencia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/icon-home-4.png">
                        <p>Servicios quiroprácticos</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                        <a href="https://asistaliavalencia.com/adaptacion-reforma-vivienda/">
                            <div class="box-home">
                                <img src="https://asistaliavalencia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/icon-home-4.png">
                                <p>Adaptación y reforma de la vivienda</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </section>
</div>
```

You can see here an image of my problem
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. bootstrap row can only consist of 12 "col"s, you have 5 elements with size 3, you need to  change all col-3 to col-2 and they will fit the row
2. or you can delete all size used from bootstrap and set sizes via % values of width attribute

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the gap by playing with first from...

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
```

to

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 text-center">
```

Keep playing with the spacing. Possibly do for last two before adjusting all.

Also add a "width:225px" to

```
.boxes-home .box-home {
   width:225px
}
```

in .css file.

Answer (score 0):

*Instead* of the `col-md-3` class for those divs, use `col-md-2` for all of them, and *add* `col-md-offset-1` only to the first of those five divs.

That way the boxes will be two columns wide each, with an offset of one column for the first div (and therefore one column space after the last one), which centers those 5 boxes: 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1 = 12 columns alltogether